# How to prevent users from reacting to multiple emojis in a Discord.js poll bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Versions:
discord.js: discord.js@14.11.0
Node: v20.2.0

I'm trying to make a poll bot based on reactions and I'm trying to limit reactions so that each user can only be reacted to one emoji at a time. Currently I have a system that checks if a user is already reacted and if so, removes and new reactions until they remove their original reaction but I'm wondering if a system that would remove the old reaction is instead possible? This is the current system I have for the limiting.

This is my current code that removes any *new* reactions but I'd like to make it remove the old reaction instead. Is this even possible?

```
interaction.client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
  //Check that the reaction is not a partial
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

  /*Check if:
  the reactor is not a bot,
  if the reaction is in a DM,
  if the message reacted to is the poll for this interaction,
  if the poll has ended and return if any are true */
  if (
    user.bot ||
    !reaction.message.guild ||
    pollMessage.id != reaction.message.id ||
    timedOut
  )
    return;

  //No new reactions emojis can be added
  if (!reactionEmojis.includes(reaction._emoji.toString())) {
    reaction.users.remove(user.id).catch(console.error);
    return;
  }

  const { message } = reaction;
  let member = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);

  //Limit reactions to member if need be
  if (roleID != null) {
    if (!member.roles.cache.has(roleID.value)) {
      reaction.users.remove(user.id).catch(console.error);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (!reactionCount.get(message))
    reactionCount.set(message, new Collection());
  const userCount = reactionCount.get(message);
  userCount.set(user, (userCount.get(user) || 0) + 1);

  if (userCount.get(user) > 1) {
    reaction.users.remove(user);
    return;
  }
  const pollMessageString = await generatePollBars(
    pollMessage,
    votingOptions
  );
  pollEmbed.setDescription(pollMessageString);
  await pollMessage.edit({ embeds: [pollEmbed] });
});

interaction.client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
  if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
  if (
    user.bot ||
    !reaction.message.guild ||
    pollMessage.id != reaction.message.id ||
    timedOut
  )
    return;

  const { message } = reaction;
  const userCount = reactionCount.get(message);
  // subtract 1 from user's reaction count
  try {
    userCount.set(user, reactionCount.get(message).get(user) - 1);
  } catch (TypeError) {}
  const pollMessageString = await generatePollBars(
    pollMessage,
    votingOptions
  );
  pollEmbed.setDescription(pollMessageString);
  await pollMessage.edit({ embeds: [pollEmbed] });
});
```

Comment: You'd have to fetch every reaction on a specific message, then see if the user is in any of the lists. From there, you can fetch the reaction and remove their reaction as displayed in the code you have provided.